# Integrating a python code(object detection code) in android studio using chaquopy

Tags: python, android-studio, chaquopy

I am trying to integrate a python code (object detection) in android studio using `chaquopy` but when testing on the phone I only get prints but nothing else works??

This is what I get when I run `logcat`:

```
{I/zygote64:Dopartialcodecachecollection,code=117KB,data=91KB/zygote64:Aftercodecache
collection,code=117KB,data=91KBIncreasingcodecachecapacityto512KBI/ViewRootImpl:jank_remveInvalidNodeallthenodeinjanklistisoutoftimeV/AudioManager:playSoundEffecteffectType:0I/python.stdout:creation
of
datasetI/python.stdout:W/InputMethodManager:startInputReason=8V/ActivityThread:
Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{e39245f
token=android.os.BinderProxy@f8d4de
com.example.radar/com.example.radar.MainActivityV/ActivityThread:
Handle window ActivityRecord{e39245f
token=android.os.BinderProxy@f8d4decom.example.radar/com.example.radar.MainActivityvisibility:falseE/BpSurfaceComposerClient:
Failed to transact (-1)E/BpSurfaceComposerClient:Failed to transact
(-1)I/ViewRootImpl: jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list
is out of timeW/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1}
```

And this is what I get when I run the code:

```
{2021-06-28 12:48:18.640 27425-27505/com.example.radarE/AwareLog:AtomicFileUtilsreadFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@4f41434
2021-06-28 12:48:20.389 27425-27475/com.example.radar E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2021-06-28 12:48:20.391 27425-27425/com.example.radar E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
2021-06-28 12:52:37.473 27425-27425/com.example.radar E/BpSurfaceComposerClient: Failed to transact (-1)
2021-06-28 12:52:37.474 27425-27425/com.example.radar E/BpSurfaceComposerClient: Failed to transact (-1)}
```

Comment: I don't think any of those log messages are relevant to your problem. Please edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do (with some example code if possible), and what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: I put all the code in an answer you can check it and thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import vehicles
import requests
#import time
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#import time
#url="http://192.168.43.1:8080/shot.jpg"
def main():
   cnt_up=0
   cnt_down=0
   print("creation of dataset")

   cap=cv2.VideoCapture("C://Users//khaoula//AndroidStudioProjects //RADAR//app//src//main//python//cars.mp4")
   print("1111")
   #Get width and height of video

   w=cap.get(3)
   h=cap.get(4)
   frameArea=h*w
   areaTH=frameArea/400
   print("2222")
   #Lines
   line_up=int(2*(h/5))
   line_down=int(3*(h/5))
   print("33333")
   up_limit=int(1*(h/5))
   down_limit=int(4*(h/5))

   #print("Red line y:",str(line_down))
   #print("Blue line y:",str(line_up))
   line_down_color=(255,0,0)
   line_up_color=(255,0,255)
   pt1 =  [0, line_down]
   pt2 =  [w, line_down]
   print("44444")
   pts_L1 = np.array([pt1,pt2], np.int32)
   pts_L1 = pts_L1.reshape((-1,1,2))
   pt3 =  [0, line_up]
   pt4 =  [w, line_up]
   pts_L2 = np.array([pt3,pt4], np.int32)
   pts_L2 = pts_L2.reshape((-1,1,2))
   print("55555")
   pt5 =  [0, up_limit]
   pt6 =  [w, up_limit]
   pts_L3 = np.array([pt5,pt6], np.int32)
   pts_L3 = pts_L3.reshape((-1,1,2))
   pt7 =  [0, down_limit]
   pt8 =  [w, down_limit]
   pts_L4 = np.array([pt7,pt8], np.int32)
   pts_L4 = pts_L4.reshape((-1,1,2))
   print("666666")
   #Background Subtractor
   fgbg=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(detectShadows=True)
   print("77777")
   #Kernals
   kernalOp = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
   kernalOp2 = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
   kernalCl = np.ones((11,11),np.uint8)
   print("88888")

   font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
   cars = []
   max_p_age = 5
   pid = 1
   print("99999")

   while (cap.isOpened()):

    print("kkkkk")
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    rows1,cols1,_=frame.shape
    print(rows1,cols1) # 1280  720
    #roi = frame[50:540, 200:960]
    #cols,rows,_=roi.shape
    #print("cols:")
    #print(cols) #490
    #print("rows:")
    #print(rows) #760

    for i in cars:
     i.age_one()
     print("i:")
     print(i)
    print("10")
    fgmask=fgbg.apply(frame)
    fgmask2=fgbg.apply(frame)
    print("11")
    if ret==True:

     #Binarization
     ret,imBin=cv2.threshold(fgmask,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
     ret,imBin2=cv2.threshold(fgmask2,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
     #OPening i.e First Erode the dilate
     mask=cv2.morphologyEx(imBin,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernalOp)
     mask2=cv2.morphologyEx(imBin2,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernalOp)

     #Closing i.e First Dilate then Erode
     mask=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernalCl)
     mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernalCl)
     print("12")


    #Find Contours
    countours0,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    print("13")
    for cnt in countours0:
        area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)

        if area>areaTH:
            ####Tracking######
            m=cv2.moments(cnt)
            cx=int(m['m10']/m['m00'])
            cy=int(m['m01']/m['m00'])
            x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            #cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 165, 255), 5)
            crop_frame=frame[y-3:y + h+3, x-3:x + w+3]

            new=True
            if cy in range(up_limit,down_limit):
                for i in cars:

                    if abs(x - i.getX()) <= w and abs(y - i.getY()) <= h:
                        new = False
                        i.updateCoords(cx, cy)

                        if i.going_UP(line_down,line_up)==True:
                            cnt_up+=1
                            print("ID:",i.getId(),'crossed going up ')#at', time.strftime("%c"))
                        elif i.going_DOWN(line_down,line_up)==True:
                            cnt_down+=1
                            print("ID:", i.getId(), 'crossed going up')# at', time.strftime("%c"))
                        break
                    if i.getState()=='1':
                        if i.getDir()=='down'and i.getY()>down_limit:
                            i.setDone()
                        elif i.getDir()=='up'and i.getY()<up_limit:
                            i.setDone()
                    if i.timedOut():
                        index=cars.index(i)
                        cars.pop(index)
                        del i
                    #file=*****************************************************************************
                    #file = "C://Users//khaoula//PycharmProjects//Radar//" + "hh.jpg"
                    #cv2.imwrite(file, i)
                if new==True: #If nothing is detected,create new
                    p=vehicles.Car(pid,cx,cy,max_p_age)
                    n=str(pid)
                    cars.append(p)
                    pid+=1

            #cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),5,(0,0,255),-1)
            #while True:
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
             #print(img)
            #crop_img = roi[y :y + h , x :x + w ]
            # s = cv2.imread(str(crop_img))
             #n = str(pid)  # +"_speed_"+str(sp)
             #file = 'C://Users//khaoula//PycharmProjects//Radar//' + n + '.jpg'
             #cv2.imwrite(file, roi)

            #print("img:")
            #print(img)
            #file = "C://Users//khaoula//PycharmProjects//Radar//" + "hh.jpg"
            #cv2.imwrite(file, img)


    for i in cars:
        cv2.putText(frame, str(i.getId()), (i.getX(), i.getY()), font, 0.3, i.getRGB(), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #crop_img = roi[i.getY():i.getY() + h, i.getX():i.getX() + w]
        file = 'C://Users//khaoula//PycharmProjects//Radar//pics//' + n + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(file, crop_frame)


        #cv2.imshow("img", frameArea)
        #t = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
        #file = "C://Users//khaoula//PycharmProjects//Radar//" + ".jpg"
        #cv2.imwrite(file, frameArea)



    str_up='UP: '+str(cnt_up)
    str_down='DOWN: '+str(cnt_down)
    frame=cv2.polylines(frame,[pts_L1],False,line_down_color,thickness=2)
    frame=cv2.polylines(frame,[pts_L2],False,line_up_color,thickness=2)
    frame=cv2.polylines(frame,[pts_L3],False,(255,255,255),thickness=1)
    frame=cv2.polylines(frame,[pts_L4],False,(255,255,255),thickness=1)
    cv2.putText(frame, str_up, (10, 40), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, str_up, (10, 40), font, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, str_down, (10, 90), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, str_down, (10, 90), font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)


    print(str_up)
    print(str_down)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xff==ord('q'):
        break

else:
    break
print("mmmmmmmmmm")
cap.release()
return cap
```

**this is the python code that i am trying to integrate in android studio and seems like the problem is coming from the while loop because i get all prints until 9999 then the app crashes i think it's because of the video that i am working on but i am not sure yet**

Comment: Unfortunately the Chaquopy build of OpenCV doesn't currently support reading video files (see [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/140)). I suggest you start off simple by just loading a single frame from a JPG or PNG file. Then once that works, you can find another method to get multiple frames from a video.

Comment: Also, it's not possible for an Android device to access files on your development machine, even if it's an emulator running on the same machine. Instead, you should load your data files either using a path relative to `__file__`, or from the external storage (“sdcard”). Both of these are explained in [the FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#read-files-in-python).

Comment: Ohh that's why it's not working , is it possible to replace the video file that i am using with real time recording from my phone camera?

Comment: The Chaquopy OpenCV build doesn't support capturing camera images directly, but you could capture the images in Java/Kotlin and then send them to Python for processing, as shown [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/303#issuecomment-637596980).

Comment: I understood,thank you so much for helping